# GTK+ title bar theme

Tags: gtk

I am making a GTK+ theme for a specific app and I was wondering if it was possible to change the title bar. I would like the apps theme and its title bar to be the same color.

is it possible to do what the person did in the second window bellow or did they most likely chose a theme that matched their OS's theme?

http://imagebin.org/321831

Answer (score 0):

I can't view the picture you attached (security policies)... but if I understand your question correctly, then the answer is

The title bar is controlled by your window manager, not by GTK.